# Laravel Socialite - google login failed “Missing required parameter: code”

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, laravel-5.6, laravel-socialite

I have this strange issue with using Laravel Socialite to log users in via Google API.

Everything configurations seem normal and ordinary, but I keep getting

> error Missing required parameter: code

But in localhost works fine

Localhost:
[image]

Server:
[image]

URI de redirection autorisés
http://example.com/subdir/auth/google/callback
http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a long search, the solution is to remove the `profile` from `scopes` in `vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\GoogleProvider.php`

```
protected $scopes = [
    'openid',
    'email',
];
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, you save a lot of my time.