# Google Authentication in Laravel5.7 php and having “Missing required parameter: code” error 400

Tags: php, laravel

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ ClientException (400)
>   Client error: `POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" }

Comment: you mean `{{csrf_field }}` ?

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52594661/laravel-socialite-google-login-failed-missing-required-parameter-code?fbclid=IwAR2nx5qZ58vP41VxPX130Heal4l-S5blhNn4IpPvPZDajPh42wkOzdzUs3E

Comment: Not duplicate as they changed parts of the configuration (specifically what's needed in config/app.php) between Laravel 5.6 and 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

Go to 
**vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\GoogleProvider.php**
Open **GoogleProvider.php**
and remove the profile from $scopes

`protected $scopes = [
    'openid',
    'email',
];`

And Check your code is running now.

Comment: When I removed profile I don't see error but the name and nickname parameter becomes null.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, was due to a misconfiguration in nginx

sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

it should be,

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

it was,

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string;
}
```

replaced "query_string" with "$query_string", query_string was not defined as a variable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The error means the code parameter not found in the requested url. You can test with any other get url arguments. Your arguments data will not found.What you are missing is your server is not passing query parameter in any form of request. If you are using nginx try

```
location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;                
       }
```